# Why the Looper.myLooper() is being equal to Looper.getMainLooper() when declaring handler in my own looper thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I am trying to learn message handling using Loopers and handlers. In the main activity, on press of start button ,I create and send a message to my `MyLooperThread` Looper object. This is my main activity code

```
package com.example.asynctaskdemo

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.Message
import android.util.Log
import com.example.asynctaskdemo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var myLooperThread: MyLooperThread
    private var myLooperThreadsLooper: Looper ?= null

    private var count = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        Log.d("MainThread","Main thread ${Thread.currentThread().id}")

        myLooperThread = MyLooperThread()
        myLooperThread.start()



        val view = binding.root

        setContentView(view)

        binding.textView.text = "0"

        binding.btnStart.setOnClickListener{
            Log.d("MainAct","Main thread ${mainLooper.thread.id}")
            val msg = Message()
            msg.obj = 2
            myLooperThread.handler!!.handleMessage(msg)

        }
        binding.btnStop.setOnClickListener{
            Log.d("MainAct","Main thread ${mainLooper.thread.id}")
            val msg = Message()
            msg.obj = 1
            myLooperThread.handler!!.handleMessage(msg)
        }




    }
}
```

This is the `MyLooperThread` class i defined ...

```
package com.example.asynctaskdemo

import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.Message
import android.util.Log


class MyLooperThread : Thread() {

    var handler: Handler ?= null


    override fun run() {
        Looper.prepare()




        handler = object : Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!) {
            override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
                // process incoming messages here
                Log.d("MyLooperThread","Looper Thread ID: ${Thread.currentThread().id}, message: ${msg.obj}")
                Log.d("MyLooperThread","Looper Thread ID: ${looper.thread.id}, message: ${msg.obj}")
                Log.d("MyLooperThread","Looper Thread is current: ${looper.isCurrentThread}, message: ${msg.obj}")
                if(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper())
                    Log.d("MyLooperThread","we are in main thread")
                else
                    Log.d("MyLooperThread","we are in looper thread")
            }
        }


        Looper.loop()
        //Looper prepare() and loop() ensure that the thread doesnt die after running
        // run() just once. run () runs
        //indefinitely unless explicitly specified because of these functions

    }


}
```

Output:

```
D/MainAct: Main thread 2
D/MyLooperThread: Looper Thread ID: 2, message: 2
D/MyLooperThread: Looper Thread ID: 497, message: 2
D/MyLooperThread: Looper Thread is current: false, message: 2
D/MyLooperThread: we are in main thread
```

My question is:

1. Why am i getting the output as I am in main thread? Basically, why Looper.myLooper is being same as Looper.getMainLooper() when the handler is being declared in the `MyLooperThread`
2. `looper.thread.id` returns id of 492 and `Thread.currentThread().id` returns id of 2. Whats the difference between these two?
3. Why `looper.isCurrentThread()` is returning false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is production code you should use HandlerThread.  But I'm going to assume this is a learning exercise and go into what's wrong.

You're calling the looper incorrectly.  You do not call Handler.handleMessage.  That will execute it on the thread you called it on (the main thread since it's in a onClick).  You call sendMessage (or post an object).  That will add a message to the handler, and the looper will call handleMessage on the correct thread.

Comment: Precise and to the point!!! I will do some research on differences between handleMessage and sendMessage but thanks